# How to apply a regex to multiple lines?

Tags: vim

let's say I want to apply the following to lines 60 through 80 in a file that I am editing in vim.

```
 :s/{/      {/
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can prefix your search command with a line range, e.g.

```
:60,80s/{/      {/
```

If you want the change to apply from line 60 and forward use `:60,s`. If you want to change the lines from current to 80 do: `:,80s`. You can even do `:.+3,80s` to apply the search between current line + 3 and line 80.

Comment: While this answer is 100% correct for the question, I prefer using visual (line) select - `V` - to see which lines I'm working with, and then simply start with the regex: `:s/....`

Answer (score 2):

You can use several type of ranges as described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges). And [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-ranges) are the official docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also mark the first line of the section that you want to apply the regex to with the m (mark) command.  Then move the cursor to the last line of the section.  Then the regex command becomes:

:'a,. s:/foo/bar/

which says, from the line marked 'a' to the current line, substitute foo with bar.